# Reasonable-seeming entries in /etc/export don't work—why?

Tags: network, nfs

I'm trying to learn more about NFS, and I'm experimenting by exporting arbitrary volumes on my M1 Air (running Ventura 13.1) and then mounting them. Often, I write a row to my `/etc/exports` file and then find that `nfsd` doesn't do what I expect; I believe it's erroring, though I haven't been able to find any error logs. I've carefully read through `man 5 exports` but even so, what works and what doesn't seems totally arbitrary to me.

In all of my experiments, I add a single row to `/etc/exports` and then run `sudo nfsd restart; sleep 3; showmount -e`. I've pasted a table of my results so far below. Does anyone know why `nfsd` is failing to come up, or `showmount -e` doesn't show any mounts in the indicated cases below?

| `/etc/exports` entry | Result |
| --- | --- |
| `/Users -network=127.0.0.1 -mask=255.0.0.0` | Works |
| `/Users -network=127.0.0.0 -mask=255.0.0.0` | `nfsd` won’t start |
| `/Users -network=127.0.0.1/8` | `showmount -e` returns nothing |
| `/Users -mapall=root -network=127.0.0.1 -mask=255.0.0.0` | Works |
| `/Users -mapall=root:root -network=127.0.0.1 -mask=255.0.0.0` | `showmount -e` returns nothing |
| `/Users/m -network=127.0.0.1 -mask=255.0.0.0` | Works |
| `/Users/m/test -network=127.0.0.1 -mask=255.0.0.0` | Works |
| `/Users/m/Documents -network=127.0.0.1 -mask=255.0.0.0` | `showmount -e` returns nothing |

N.B. In the cases where I've written "`showmount -e` returns nothing", the specific output is this:

```
$ showmount -e
Exports list on localhost:

$
```

Where I've written "`nfsd` won't start", the output is:

```
$ showmount -e
showmount: Cannot retrieve info from host: localhost: RPC: Program not registered
```

Removing the line and then running `sudo nfsd restart` seems to fix it in these cases.

Comment: Seems obvious in retrospect, but `man nfsd` revealed the existence of the `nfsd checkexports` command (and `nfsd verbose up` which coaxes `nfsd` to post startup errors to `syslog`). If I'm able to answer my questions with those, I'll post the answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nfsd checkexports` has given me a lot of information about what's going wrong. There are still a few mysteries, but here's what it outputs:

| `/etc/exports` entry | `checkexports` output |
| --- | --- |
| `/Users -network=127.0.0.1 -mask=255.0.0.0` | - |
| `/Users -network=127.0.0.0 -mask=255.0.0.0` | `[1] 13001 segmentation fault nfsd checkexports` |
| `/Users -network=127.0.0.1/8` | `Bad net: 127.0.0.1/8 exports:1: error processing options: -network=127.0.0.1/8` (this format is not claimed to work in `man 5 exports`, so it's my mistake to have tried it) |
| `/Users -mapall=root -network=127.0.0.1 -mask=255.0.0.0` | - |
| `/Users -mapall=root:root -network=127.0.0.1 -mask=255.0.0.0` | `Unknown group: root. no groups found: (null). map credential error.` (N.B. And using `root:staff` seems to work) |
| `/Users/m -network=127.0.0.1 -mask=255.0.0.0` | - |
| `/Users/m/test -network=127.0.0.1 -mask=255.0.0.0` | - |
| `/Users/m/Documents -network=127.0.0.1 -mask=255.0.0.0` | `exports:1: sandbox_check failed. nfsd has no read access to "/Users/m/Documents”` (N.B. Going to "System Settings" > "Privacy & Security" > "Full Disk Access" and giving full disk access to `/sbin/nfsd` fixes this) |

The `segmentation fault` on `127.0.0.0` seems like it must be a bug in `nfsd` that would be nice to understand, but other than that, I think I largely understand these issues now.